# Running the AREG command in SPSS without overriding previous output

Tags: python, statistics, spss

I am attempting to use the AREG command in SPSS to run a Cochrane-Orcutt transformation on multiple subjects at one time. My data file contains about 80 participants (Named "V1, V2, V3, ..., V80"), and a time variable called "Time" (in seconds). My syntax to run the AREG command on participant #1 currently looks like this:

/AREG Var1 with Time

/Method=CO

/RHO=.9.

The output of this syntax gives me my desired, new, "Fit" variable (along with a couple other variables that I don't need). My problem arises when I try to run participant #2:

/AREG V2 with Time

/Method=CO

/RHO=.9.

Running this second set of syntax removes the first "Fit" variable for Subject 1, and replaces it with the new "Fit" variable for Subject 2. I would like to keep the first "Fit" variable for participant #1 AND participant #2 (without it overriding the output every time) Is there a way to use macros/loops/etc. in SPSS to run participants #1-80 at one time and have a unique "Fit" variable for each subject? I am trying to avoid having to copy and paste each new "Fit" variable for each new participant that I run before I run the next one (I have about 100 data sets total, each with ~80 participants, so this would take days). Maybe there is an easier way to do it with Python?

Thank you very much for your help and time!

Answer (score 0):

The help says that you can use `TSET NEWVARS=ALL` to have new variables written each time.

```
DATA LIST FREE / Ord X Y1 Y2.
BEGIN DATA
1 1 2 2.5
2 2 3.5 3.0
3 4 6.2 5.4
4 1 3.0 2.7
5 6 9 9
6 10 3 4
7 11 15 6
8 14 12 13
END DATA.

*Creates new variables.
TSET NEWVAR=ALL.
AREG Y1 WITH X.
AREG Y2 WITH X.
```

So this produces `FIT_1`, `FIT_2`, etc. A way to not have to write (or make a macro to loop through) the 70 variables though is to reshape the data using `VARSTOCASES` and then use `SPLIT FILE`.

```
*Reshape wide to long.
ADD FILES FILE = * /DROP ERR_1 TO SEP_1 ERR_2 TO SEP_2.
VARSTOCASES 
  /MAKE Y FROM Y1 Y2 
  /MAKE FitOrig FROM FIT_1 FIT_2
  /INDEX YOrig (Y).
SORT CASES BY YOrig Ord.
SPLIT FILE BY YOrig.
AREG Y WITH X.
SPLIT FILE OFF.
```

You can see that this produces equivalent estimates of the fitted values. (Note in your use case you can use `TO` to specify sequential variables on `VARSTOCASES`, e.g. you could use `VARSTOCASES /MAKE Y FROM Y1 TO Y70.` as long as they are sequentially ordered in your original file.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help Andy W! I wasn't quite sure where to turn for a specific SPSS problem such as this, but you hit the nail right on the head. Keep up your much valued work, we all appreciate it :)